# drupal webform cannot send out emails

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform

I am using Drupal7, when I enable the module "Webform Select Email", the other webform could not send out email. I have no idea what's going on there.

Have you guys met this before?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can provide with last few log entries from your Drupal and apache logs. Please make sure both the modules do not override each other's functions in recursive manner!